# Setting up Derby on MacOS Sierra

Tags: java, derby, macos-sierra

I am following Java: How To Program - Chapter 24. The chapter deals with database implementation in Java. I followed the steps to setup "Derby", but I get the error `java.sql.SQLException: Database 'books' not found.`.

I checked $PATH to make sure it includes $DERBY_HOME. $DERBY_HOME points to the correct folder(`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/db`).

I checked $JAVA_HOME and it was also setup correctly(`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home`).

I can use the tool `ij` and it shows me the database that is setup. I added `derby.jar` to the package in eclipse. The following is the code from the book, but when I compile it I get the error `java.sql.SQLException: Database 'books' not found.`

I looked it up online, and there were recommendations that I add `//localhost:1527/books`. But if I add that I get the `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/books` error.

There was also suggestions that I use `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();`, that didn't solve the problem either.

I have copy/pasted the `books.sql` database in the same package as the one that contains the source code.

Does anybody know how to solve the problem? I am running MacOS Sierra.

```
public class DisplayAuthors {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby:books";
        final String SELECT_QUERY = "Select authorID, firstName, lastName from authors";


        try(    
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                DATABASE_URL, "deitel", "deitel");
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY)){

            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int numberOfCols = metaData.getColumnCount();

            System.out.printf("Authors of table of Books databse:%n%n");
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCols; i++)
                System.out.printf("%-8s\t",metaData.getColumnName(i));

            System.out.println();

            while(resultSet.next()){
                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCols; i++)
                     System.out.printf("%-8s\t",resultSet.getObject(i));
                     System.out.println();
            }

        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a code issue.  You just need to create the data base. Look at the execute() method on statement and the CREATE TABLE ddl command.

Comment: @ChrisGerken the database is already created. I can see all the data that is in the database via commandline (ij tool).

Comment: @ChrisGerken thanks, I figured that database was the problem. I had created the database, but the location was different. Figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem was. When the creating the database via `ij` I had to be in the same directory that the source file is. Now under eclipse I thought that this would mean I need to be under package folder(JAVAProject/src/package), but that was wrong. I had to be under (JAVAProject).